# FATAL: Invalid id: Process leaked file descriptors - Jenkins (github)

Tags: github, jenkins-plugins

I am getting following error in jenkins with github.

> Using strategy: Default
>   Last Built Revision: Revision 8d7d3f0898bc4583a80848033d6e0d27cc3e2096 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
>   Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
>   Fetching upstream changes from origin
>   Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
>   Seen branch in repository origin/master
>   Seen branch in repository origin/svn
>   Seen 3 remote branches
>   Commencing build of Revision 8d7d3f0898bc4583a80848033d6e0d27cc3e2096 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
>   Checking out Revision 8d7d3f0898bc4583a80848033d6e0d27cc3e2096 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
>   FATAL: Invalid id: Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid id: Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId.fromString(ObjectId.java:232)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.doRevList(CliGitAPIImpl.java:959)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.revList(CliGitAPIImpl.java:945)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.isCommitInRepo(CliGitAPIImpl.java:970)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.isCommitInRepo(GitAPI.java:181)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.computeChangeLog(GitSCM.java:1292)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.access$1300(GitSCM.java:58)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1257)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1211)
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:909)
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:882)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1211)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1408)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:676)
>       at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:581)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1603)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247)

Normally it works fine during the day and when I start my system again on next day, it gives this error and can only be resolved by re-installing the github in Jenkins. The link in the error message says about Spawning process from build but I don't understand what does that mean (I run 1-2 builds only; on windows).

Thanks.